# CryptographicException exception when setting up SSL handshake with MailKit using .NET Core

Tags: ssl, .net-core, openssl, mailkit

What we are trying to do is send an email from a pod (running Linux based on the image "microsoft/dotnet") on a client's Openshift environment using MailKit:
https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

We get an exception thrown when trying to set up the SSL Handshake:

- MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while
  attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.
- System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred
  during a cryptographic operation

We have tried using the.NET SMTP client as well and it **worked** (using a secure connection)! Unfortunately this component is now obsolete and Microsoft recommends to use MailKit.

Going through the .NET source code the exception raised is a generic catch all exception which looks like it comes from unexpected code returned from the OpenSSL library. Unfortunately I can't see how to get the error code (it is logged using "Debug.Fail", but I am unable to setup a trace to see it) so I am not sure what it is.

I have written a test just to build the X509Chain. When we have the Revocation Mode set to Online (the default) we get the exception. When the revocation is disabled it seems to build the chain OK.

When I run the test on our Test Openshift environment that is totally independent to the client's we get the following error, but do not see the exception: "unable to get certificate CRL"

The only thing I have noticed about the Revocation List is that there is a LDAP and HTTP URLs. Perhaps there is an issue processing the LDAP URL?

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should report to github.com/microsoft/dotnet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have created the issue on GitHub: [https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/973](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/973)